# How to hot reload grpc-server in python?

Tags: python, docker, grpc, grpc-python

I'm developing some python microservices with grpc and i'm using docker for the cassandra database and the microservices. Is there a way to setup reload on change within docker-compose?

I'm guessing that first I need the code mounted as a volume but I don't see a way to reload on GRPC server like for example flask does.

Comment: Hi Luis. We like to use https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog in combination with docker. All you do is add watchdog to your requirements.txt file, and in your docker-compose.yml file add `command: watchmedo auto-restart --recursive --pattern="*.py" --directory="/path/to/your/app" python -- -m server`

Comment: I think this solves my problems. Thanks! Mind putting it as an answer? so I can accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use `watchdog[watchmedo]` with our grpc services and Docker.

Install watchdog or add to your `requirements.txt` file

`python -m pip install watchdog[watchmedo]`

Then in your `docker-compose.yml` add `watchmedo auto-restart --recursive --pattern="*.py" --directory="/usr/src/app/" python -- -m app` to your container where `--directory` is the directory to where your app is contained inside the docker container, and `python -- -m app` is the file that starts your grpc Server. In this example the file that starts the server is called `app.py`:

```
  app:
    build:
      context: ./app/
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      target: app
    command: watchmedo auto-restart --recursive --pattern="*.py" --directory="/usr/src/app/" python -- -m app
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
```